# Liferay Layout not working

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 CE.

I am trying to use 1-2-1 layout in my page.

But i cant Drag n Drop portlets to the 2 column in my page.also 1-2-1 is not working properly.

What is the reason?

this is 1_2_1.column.tpl

```
<div class="columns-1-2-1" id="main-content" role="main">
#if ($browserSniffer.isIe($request) && $browserSniffer.getMajorVersion($request) < 8)
    <table class="portlet-layout">
    <tr>
        <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-1">
            $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="portlet-layout">
    <tr>
        <td class="aui-w50 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-2">
            $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
        </td>
        <td class="aui-w50 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-3">
            $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="portlet-layout">
    <tr>
        <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-4">
            $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
#else
    <div class="portlet-layout">
        <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-1">
            $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet-layout">
        <div class="aui-w50 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-2">
            $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
        </div>

        <div class="aui-w50 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-3">
            $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet-layout">
        <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-4">
            $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
        </div>
    </div>
#end
```

Comment: You are working on a clean liferay bundle or you have customized your theme? Also what is exactly not working can you elaborate, a screen-shot explaining what you are trying to do would also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @PrakashK..Actually the problem with the social office theme..In classic liferay theme,its working fine..but in social office,pages are in the left side so 3 column or 2 column is not working..what is the solution?

Comment: please show your complete layout template (1-2-1)

Comment: @MartinGamulin updated my question with the 1-2-1 template file

Comment: which version of social office theme do you use, I just tried with so-theme-6.1.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558.war and it does work. And, at least in snippet above, you are missing </div> after #end.

Comment: @MartinGamulin..Am using liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558.war,social office installed through market place.</div> missing is a copy paste mistake..still  it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging portlets to the "2" portion of the 1-2-1 template wasn't working for me either.  It may be an issue with the Social Office theme.  I switched the page back to the classic theme, added the portlets, and then switched back to the SO theme.  I now have the 1-2-1 layout with the Social Office theme applied.

hth